# How to replace regex in all files that match this regex

Tags: text-processing

Let's assume that I have some files(in a directory tree - for example, `~/home`) that may something I am looking for: e.g. I'm looking for a string `a.2` and I want to change it for `b.3`. I know that I can list them by running `grep -R 'a\.2' *`. This will show me matches, prepended with filenames. However, I don't know how to replace them. How can I do that?

Comment: @don_crissti I'll happily see my question closed as a duplicate if an answer already exists.

Answer (score 3):

There is no reason to double read file(s) (first by grep, next by sed)

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/a\.2/b\.3/g' {} +
```

Comment: @don_crissti sam as Rhaul's version, but I never said that I do mind. In fact, I want to replace the strings in the files, not create new ones.

Comment: No need to escape the dot in `s/.../b.3/`.

Comment: @MatthewRock - it's not the same, buddy... this one will "edit" (read "modify") _all_ files in place even those that don't contain the string `a.2`

Comment: Now I see. Thanks @don_crissti : this is something I wouldn't want.